# Equivalent Capacitance

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electricity, electric-circuits, capacitance

What is the equivalent capacitance between A and B? 
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

The 10 micro farad capacitor can be <s>removed</s> ignored since it gets stuck in a wheatstone like network.

Comment: That's a BIG hint.